# Adding custom print size to photoshop cc

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I have an image that is like to print on the front of an a7 (7.25” x 5.25”) envelope. The size of the image is the same size of the envelope. I created the image in photoshop, and can export to any format so that I can use another program if needed. But I cannot seem to figure out how to do this, as I’m not seeing a customs size that I can create.

MS Word lets you print envelopes, but not a full size image.

I’m running Windows 10, using a Canon imageCLASS MF634Cdw, and can’t seem to do anything in the printer settings itself from Windows either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Do *File > New*

Choose any preset from the Web presets (you don't want a CMYK file for printing on a home/office printer - should be RGB for these kind of printers)

Set the units to Inches, and add the custom size by typing it in the preset details panel. Set the resolution to 300ppi. Hit *Create*.

Copy and paste the content you made previously into the new document. Resize/position it as necessary.

[image]